# How do I debug node.js in Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015. On the command line if I do

```
npm start
```

Here is what is in my package.json in scripts.start:

```
"start": "concurrently \"ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json\" \"nodemon server.js\"",
```

my project starts working. But I wish to run it from Visual Studio and debug. I have install NodeJs Tools for Visual Studio.

This is how my project properties dialog looks like:

[image]

What do I write here so the project starts correctly and I can debug the project?

I made some progress. I put this in my `node.exe options`

```
.\node_modules\.bin\concurrently ".\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json" ".\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js server.js"
```

But I now I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Don't you need `debug` on the command line?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: No I am wanting to debug it directly by pressing F5 in VS.